# Is there a way to do a "full file buffering" inside a chain of piped commands?

Tags: shell-script, files, io-redirection, cat

Very often I do simple operations on a file, for example:

```
cat file1.txt|sed -r 's/^ *//'
```

to remove spaces at the beginning of the line.
If I want to overwrite the file, the only way I know is:

```
cat file1.txt|sed -r 's/^ *//' > file2.txt
mv file2.txt file1.txt
```

This is very ennoying, because I have to check if file2.txt exists, because I have to write two commands instead of one, and so on.

So I thought: is there a way to do a full file buffering inside a chain of piped commands? So i could write:

```
cat file1.txt| magicbuffercommand |sed -r 's/^ *//' > file1.txt
```

This command should buffer (until a maximum of bytes, of course) and wait for an EOF, and then should start to write to stdout.

Is there anything that can do such a thing?

Comment: To all people saying things like "you can do it with -i switch of sed" or "useless use of cat command", and similar, this is just an example. Replace it with any other command, maybe it's sed, maybe it's "cat -n", maybe it's sort, and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You don't need the `cat`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat). `sed` happily accepts the file name as argument:

```
sed 's/^ *//' <file>
```

If you use GNU sed you can use the `-i` or `--in-place` switch to edit the
file in place:

```
sed -i 's/^ *//' <file>
```

To answer the question, you can achieve “full file buffering” using the tool
`sponge` from the [moreutils package](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/moreutils/). Using
`sponge` you can do:

```
<command> <file> | sponge <file>  # or
<command1> < <file> | <command2> | sponge <file>
```

Using your `sed` example this becomes:

```
sed 's/^ *//' <file> | sponge <file>
```

Comment: Wonderful, sponge is exact what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the Linux buffer command?  This utilizes a user shared memory segment to basically allow concurrent reads/writes.  I suppose that it could buffer an entire file if the shared memory segment is large enough.

The buffer command might not be automatically installed, but I have found the program in many of the repositories on different Linux distributions.  At worse, you can google and find the source and compile/link it yourself.

I have used buffer to speed up writes to slower devices such as tape drives and it does reduce the transfer time about 10-20%.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to use `-i` switch of (GNU) [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), so

```
sed -i -r 's/^ *//' file_to_replace_in_place.txt
```

and for Os X :

```
sed -i.'' -r 's/^ *//' file_to_replace_in_place.txt
```

Another (more generic) solution is to use [tee](/questions/tagged/tee) :

```
cat file | sed 's/^ *//' | tee file
```

you have to take care of huge files, this can exit without error, nor change.

Comment: tee is not a solution http://askubuntu.com/a/752451

Answer (score 0):

One other possibility is to put the entire contents of a file into a shell variable.  There used to be a limit on the size, but I understand that this is no longer a problem.   As long as you have the memory (of course exceeding physical memory would cause swapping) you can try the following:

For example:

```
 varx=`cat filename`
 echo "$varx" | sed ..... >$filename
```

I only mention this in the event you may want to so something other than a sed command.

Answer (score 0):

Useless use of the cat command. Use sed directly to print the contents or use `-i` to do an in place edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '%s/^ *//|x' file1.txt
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `s` substitute
3. `x` save and close